# How to get rid of click effect on custom row listview?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to disable click effect on row. I have used custom row which i have bind to ArrayAdapter. I have tried `android:clickable="false", android:focusable="false"` on ListView, also on TextView, buttons, and imageview which i have used for displaying in the row.

Here is my "web_message_list.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/exclamation_feather_top"
    >

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/titleArea"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/top_head">


     <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/btn_Cancel"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/cancel"
         android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:visibility="gone"

         />   
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_title"
        style="?customTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
        android:text="Messages" />  
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/edit_btn"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"        
        android:src="@drawable/edit_button"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnDone"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"         
        android:src="@drawable/done_button"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"        />

    </RelativeLayout>


     <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/android:list"
        style="@style/blackContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/titleArea"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >
    </ListView>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

and "web_msg_list.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/top_head"
    android:id="@+id/titleArea2"

   >
<TextView 
            android:id="@+id/btnBck"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"        
        android:background="@drawable/messages"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
            />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/usr_name"
        style="?customTitle"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"

       />

         <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/btnUserInfo"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"      
         android:layout_marginTop="3dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/userinfo"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
            />

</RelativeLayout>


 <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/alarmLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/titleArea2"
      android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
      android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
      android:padding="3dp" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblmessage1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstDivider" 
            android:autoLink="web"
            />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/firstDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblmessage1"
            android:background="@drawable/container_divider" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblmessage2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstDivider"
            android:layout_below="@id/firstDivider"

            android:autoLink="web"
            />

                <View
            android:id="@+id/secondDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/lblmessage2"
            android:background="@drawable/container_divider" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblmessage3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/secondDivider"
            android:layout_below="@id/secondDivider"
            android:textSize="5dp" />

         <View
            android:id="@+id/thirdDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/lblmessage3"
            android:background="@drawable/container_divider" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblmessage4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thirdDivider"
            android:layout_below="@id/thirdDivider"
            android:textSize="5dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

It's still the same, this is what style="@style/blackContainer" has

```
<style name="blackContainer" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView.Menu">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/container</item>                      
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/container_divider</item>
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/container_item_selector</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>           
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">false</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:scrollbars">none</item>
        <item name="android:fastScrollEnabled">true</item>
    </style>
```

and

@drawable/container_item_selector is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by effect? The selection? Use this line in your `ListView` tag. `android:listSelector="#00000000"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What i wanted to say was that, when i click on the row, all of the elements(textview, imageview, button) show flick effect, only when clicked. I have tried what you have suggested, and now the whole row alongwith the border of the listview(row) is blinking on click. and thankyou

Answer (score 6):

If you want do disable the selection effect just add this to your Xml file, in the ListView section:

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Hey OfirAN, thanks for the reply, what i wanted to convey was that, the content in the row is blinking when i touch on the row, which i don't want. Using your suggestion is now showing click effect, with color on click being orange. thnks

Answer (score 1):

Now I've understand your problem. It's a black flick, right? Try this. Add this to your `ListView` tag

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

In java code took your layout (whereever you want to remove click effect) then set `yourLayout.setOnClickListener(null);` This will solve your problems.

Comment: That would disable the `OnClickListener`, so nothing would happen when `yourLayout` is clicked. It´s just needed to disable the effect.

Answer (score 0):

add below lines to your listView:

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```